# Adding link to an image inserted into header.php

Tags: php, image, header

```
        <?php

$image = "image-link.png"; 
$width = 300;
$height = 280;
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" style=width:"' . $width . 'px;height:' . $height . 'px;">';
?>
```

I just want to be able to click on the image and it will go to an external link. I am confused on how to do this next step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><img src="'.$image.'" style=width:"'
  . $width . 'px;height:' . $height . 'px;"></a>';
```

Now clicking the image will take you to stackoverflow.com

Comment: that did the trick. I had a plugin that was enabled which caused an issue. Your the man